# What's the difference between these similar Java regexes?

Tags: java, regex

Are these three related Java regexes just different syntaxes for doing the same thing?

```
String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll("(?m)^\\d+\\.\\s*", "");
String resultString = subjectString.replace("^[0-9]+\\. *", "");
String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll('\\d+\.\\s+', '');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they are different:

- `(?m)^\\d+\\.\\s*` matches

  - one or more digits at the **begin of a line** (note *m* modifier in `(?m)`), followed by
  - a literal `.`, followed by
  - **zero** or more **whitespace characters** (equivalent to `[ \t\n\x0B\f\r]`);
- `^[0-9]+\\. *` matches

  - one or more digits at the **begin of the string**, followed by
  - a literal `.`, followed by
  - **zero** of more **spaces**;
- `\\d+\.\\s+` matches

  - one or more digits **at any position**, followed by
  - a literal `.`, followed by
  - **one** or more **whitespace characters**.

Besides that, as [Adrian Smith has noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158123/whats-the-difference-between-these-similar-java-regexes/4158146#4158146), `replace` does not expect a regular expression but a single *char* or a *CharacterSequence* (*String* implements that interface).

Answer (score 3):

`replace` doesn't accept a regexp; it accepts a literal string (i.e. will really search for exactly those characters). `replaceAll` accepts a regexp.

The third one isn't valid because single quotes are used. Single quotes represent individual characters which are `char`. Double quotes create strings (multiple characters) which are `String`s.

Answer (score 0):

Close, each replace a number followed by a period followed by *white-space*, i.e. `11.`. But each one has slight difference:

The first will replace requires that the digit be at the beginning of a line and the white-space can be anything, i.e. a tab.

The second isn't valid, as noted, but if it were `replaceAll()` the white-space could only be the space character.

The third doesn't have to be at the beginning of the line and will replace any white-space characters like the first one.

The other differences are simply syntax.